# Clear top value of an element in jquery.animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this css:

```
.hacer .contenido .caja .texto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
}
```

and I have this jquery

```
 var cajasHacer = $('.hacer').find('.contenido').find('.caja');

        cajasHacer.each(function () {

        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find('.texto').animate({top: '40px'} , 300);
        });

        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).find('.texto').animate({ top: 'auto'} , 300);
        });
    });
```

I have used values for top: initial,unset and auto, but it doesn't clear the top value of the element and travel to bottom again when mouse leaves.

Comment: please post the actual code and not screenshots of it

Comment: Try `auto` instead of `initial`

Comment: dont work with auto, i tried it before

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: You need to get the initial top and store it in a data attribute so that you can use it when animating back to it's initial position (if the initial top value isn't 0)

Comment: the initial  value of top is auto, which is the default of the browser(i only write the bottom property in css), but when i write auto in mouseleave, it dont work.

Comment: You cannot animate non arithmetic values. One way is to read the calculated top value and apply it, and at the second animation animate to that and after the animation set it to auto.

Comment: Are you sure this wouldn't be solved if you use animate({top: '-40px'} , 300); for the mouseleave function?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the top value through removing the style attribute values using `.removeAttr()` method.

```
var cajasHacer = $('.hacer').find('.contenido').find('.caja');

    cajasHacer.each(function () {

    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find('.texto').animate({top: '40px'} , 300);
    });

    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('.texto').removeAttr('style');
    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Le81zfv2/)

Comment: the problem is not that the problem is do that with a animation. but 1 guy have said that we can not  animate non-aritmetic values

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should store the initial top value of the element in a variable. So, when the `mouseleave` event triggers, you can add it to your element.

```
var topPos = $(element).offset().top;
```

and in your code:

```
var cajasHacer = $('.hacer').find('.contenido').find('.caja');

        cajasHacer.each(function () {

        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find('.texto').animate({top: '40px'} , 300);
        });

        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).find('.texto').animate({ top: topPos} , 300);
        });
    });
```